# How to stop protocols from generating warnings?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

if I have a protocal defined, then it always generate a lot of warnings when compile.

like

```
@property (retain) id <SomeProc> value
```

then in the code:
 `[value class]; ...
[value release]` 
the compiler always complain it "may not have class or release defined".

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
@protocol SomeProc <NSObject>
…
@end
```

This way your protocol will also contain all the methods required by the [NSObject protocol](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html).